# Edit links in table not connecting to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am having an issue editing mysql database through a html table.

when I run a simple while loop it works, I can pull in the data and update the database:

**Working Code**

```
<?php


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        echo "$row[id]. $row[Key_Role] .$row[Incumbant] .$row[Attrition_Risk] .$row[Ready_Now] .$row[lowerYears] .$row[higherYears]<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a> <br />";

?>
```

However, when I run the php through a table, the edit links no longer pull in the data from mysql and I am not able to update information. I have put below the index and edit php files.

**Index.php**

```
<?php

        include_once('db.php');


        if(ISSET($_POST['Key_Role']))

        {

        $Key_Role = $_POST['Key_Role'];
        $Incumbant = $_POST['Incumbant'];
        $Attrition_Risk = $_POST['Attrition_Risk'];
        $Ready_Now = $_POST['Ready_Now'];
        $lowerYears = $_POST['1-2_Years'];
        $higherYears = $_POST['3-5_Years'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tmdata VALUES('','$Key_Role','$Incumbant','$Attrition_Risk','$Ready_Now','$lowerYears','$higherYears')";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>"; 
        if ($res)
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
        else 
                echo "Failed";
        } else {

            echo "please enter a key Role";
        }


        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tmdata");



    ?>
    <style>

    <?php include 'style.css' ?>

    </style>

    <H1 class="Title">Talent Management System</H1>

    <form action="." method="post">

    Key Role:<input type="text" name="Key_Role">
    Incumbant:<input type="text" name="Incumbant">
    Attrition_Risk:<input type="text" name="Attrition_Risk">
    Ready_Now:<input type="text" name="Ready_Now">
    1-2_Years:<input type="text" name="1-2_Years">
    3-5_Years:<input type="text" name="3-5_Years">


    <input type ="submit" value="Enter">


    </form>



    <h1> List Of Key Roles</h1>

    <?php
    /*

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            echo "$row[id]. $row[Key_Role] .$row[Incumbant] .$row[Attrition_Risk] .$row[Ready_Now] .$row[lowerYears] .$row[higherYears]<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a> <br />";
    */
    ?>


    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Key_Role</th>
                <th>Incumbant</th>
                <th>Attrition_Risk</th>
                <th>Ready_Now</th>
                <th>1-2_Years</th>
                <th>3-5_Years</th>  
                <th>Edit</th>  
            </tr>
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)):;?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Key_Role'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Incumbant'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Attrition_Risk'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Ready_Now'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['lowerYears'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['higherYears'];?></td>
                <td><a href='edit.php?edit=$row["id"]'>edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php

    include_once('db.php');

    if (isset($_GET["edit"]))
    {

        $id = $_GET["edit"];
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tmdata WHERE id='".$id."'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);


    }

    if( isset($_POST['newKey_Role']) || isset($_POST['newIncumbant']) || isset($_POST['newAttrition_Risk']) || isset($_POST['newReady_Now']) || isset($_POST['newLowerYears']) || isset($_POST['newHigherYears']) )
    {

        $newKey_Role = $_POST['newKey_Role'];
        $newIncumbant = $_POST['newIncumbant'];
        $newAttrition_Risk = $_POST['newAttrition_Risk'];
        $newReady_Now = $_POST['newReady_Now'];
        $newLowerYears = $_POST['newLowerYears'];
        $newHigherYears = $_POST['newHigherYears'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $sql = "UPDATE tmdata SET Key_Role='$newKey_Role', Incumbant='$newIncumbant', Attrition_Risk='$newAttrition_Risk', Ready_Now='$newReady_Now', lowerYears='$newLowerYears', higherYears='$newHigherYears' WHERE id='".$id."'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";

    }


?>


<form action="edit.php" method="post">

Key Role:<input type="text" name="newKey_Role" value ="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>"></input> <br />
Incumbant:<input type="text" name="newIncumbant" value ="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>"></input> <br />
Attrition_Risk:<input type="text" name="newAttrition_Risk" value ="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>"></input> <br />
Ready_Now:<input type="text" name="newReady_Now" value ="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>"></input> <br />
1-2 Years:<input type="text" name="newLowerYears" value ="<?php echo $row[5]; ?>"></input> <br />
3-5 Years:<input type="text" name="newHigherYears" value ="<?php echo $row[6]; ?>"></input> <br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value ="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">

<input type ="submit" value="Update">


</form>

<style>

<?php include 'style.css' ?>

</style>
```

It looks as though the ID is not pulling across to the edit php. I also tried manually inputting the id in the table:

```
<td><a href='edit.php?edit=$row[184]'>edit</a></td>
```

but this also did not work.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the `.` dots in the where line there because you want dots in the output or do you think you are concatenating

Comment: The dots helped to show whether all the outputs were displaying in the working example as the fields don't show if there is no data in the sql table. 

The part that isn't working is, that when I click edit, none of the fields are populated and when I update the fields it doesn't update the sql database. Yes, the form is for adding a new row, the edit buttons are to edit data that is already present in the table. So I click edit, on a row and the form fields are blank when it should bring up the information that is in the table for that row. It does work when not displayed as a table.

Comment: When you click an anchor `<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a>` ALL THAT is passed to PHP is what you put on the querystring. In this case only `$_GET['edit']` will be passed. It is passed to the `$_GET` array and not the `$_POST` array

Comment: When you click a SUBMIT button in a FORM all the `<input>` values (that have a `name="xxx"` attribute) get passed to the `$_POST` array

Comment: Yes, so this should pass the id of that row. Which then in edit should pick that up in GET. However it looks as though it is not picking that id up. However, when I do the same with the links in a simple while loop. It works.

Comment: Ok lets start with Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I am still new to programming but I have added the code to the top of both index.php and edit.php and no errors seem to be showing on the webpage or in the developer tools.

Comment: I am still not sure I understand the issue (I'm Dumb) Are you expecting the UPDATE to be run, when you click on the anchor link?

Comment: No, just opening the edit page that refers to the sql row. I have tested a little bit. When the edit button is in a table edit pushes '$row[id]' as a sting but in the while loop edit pushes id (the actual number)

Comment: Everything comes from the browser as a string

Comment: When you click the link and run `edit.php` the current page in the browser is lost. A new one should be created by `edit.php` Try adding the basic `<html><body>` before you output the new `<form>` and of course the `</body><\html>` at the end

Comment: I have added the html and body, no luck. When I say string i mean when I echo $id it shows either '$row["id"]' or '184' depending on whether it is in a table or not. I want it to be '184' but this doesn't happen when in a table.

Comment: THat will just be that you are coding the one that shows '$row["id"]' wrong somewhere

Comment: That's the thing. When it is not in a table the excat line of code "<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a>" Works Fine. But when in a table it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you need to put the  link in php.

```
<td><?php echo "<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a>"?></td>
```

That worked in the end.